# Clarification for question: Homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z / n \to \Bbb C_{\ne 0}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Please don't solve the problem - it is for an assignment - this is just a question for clarification purposes.

---

Let $G$ be a group and $\hat G$ be the set of homomorphisms from $G$ to the group of non-zero complex numbers.

Q: Show that $\hat{Z/n}$ is a cyclic group of order $n$.

SubQ: Define a binary operation on $\hat G$ as follows: If $\alpha,\beta \in \hat G$ we let $\alpha \circ \beta $ be the function that maps $\alpha \circ \beta:g\mapsto \alpha(g) \beta(g) $

I have already done this part.

---

> My question: Do they want to to show that the group of all homomorphisms as defined by the mapping above from $\Bbb Z / n\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb C_{\ne 0}$, is a cyclic group itself and that this cyclic group has $n$ elements?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what they want you to prove. Note that any homomorphism is completely determined by what it does at $\overline{1} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. That should help you get started

Comment: @Prahlad Could I hassle you for an example of this unique determination by what it does to the identity(Edit : oh does $\overline 1$ refer to the additive generator?)? Is this related to group actions?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Oh I see what you mean, since $\phi(3)=\phi(1)+\phi(1)+\phi(1)$ and so on, knowing how $\phi(1)$ gets mapped gives us everything.